How does Apache Flink HA react if a new job version is deployed without stopping the previous job?
I've an application mode Apache Flink installation deployed as a standalone docker image over Kubernetes. The job is running in High Availability with Zookeeper.
The documentation says HA keeps the job artifacts.
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/ha/overview/

In order to recover submitted jobs, Flink persists metadata and the job artifacts. The HA data will be kept until the respective job either succeeds, is cancelled or fails terminally. Once this happens, all the HA data, including the metadata stored in the HA services, will be deleted.

What would happen if I were to deploy a new docker image with updated job code, to a K8 deployment with recreate and without cancelling or stopping the previously running job?
Will the newly bundled jar in the image start executing, or will the HA recover the old artifacts and the Flink application cluster will continue executing the previous job?
